# Is there a name for manifolds that can be covered by a single chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, manifolds, definition

this is more of a definitional question, but I'm wondering if there's a name or term for a manifold that can be covered by a single chart. More precisely, I'm speaking of manifolds for which there exists an atlas containing only one chart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many 2-manifolds can be covered by a single chart?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843732/how-many-2-manifolds-can-be-covered-by-a-single-chart)

Comment: Note that the other answer is about 2-manifolds but there is little that changes in the general case: either the name is "$\Bbb R^n$" or "open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$", depending on what chart means.